# Login with cURL php Cookie

Tags: php, curl, cookies, authentication

I need help to make a login like the one shown in the image. (www.hurl.it)
[image: hurl.it]

This should be done in PHP with cURL.
This is what I have so far but it does not work for me:

```
$c = curl_init('https://www.mkr.cl/users/login?redirect=/store/product/22207');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1 );
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'username=76696459-1&password=7669');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
$result = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: How specifically does it not work? Do you get an error? How does the result differ from what you expect?

Comment: i haven't confirmed it, but most likely they refuse to login anyone without a valid session id. so first thing, grab a session id from the login page with a GET request, and then, when you actually have a session ID, do the login POST request, with the cookie session id.

Comment: edit: now i have checked it, i was wrong. if you try to login without a session id, you will obtain 1 in the POST request itself, and you will get logged in. in fact, your curl code DOES log in successfully when i testrun it here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code works correctly, and does in fact log in, when i testrun it here. i voted to close this question, because you just say "it does not work for me", without explaining HOW it does not work for you.

but, when debugging, don't use `print_r` , use `var_dump`. for example, if `curl` gets an error, it returns **bool(false)**, and when you give bool(false) to `print_r`, it prints absolutely nothing, giving you no clue what happens.

however, if you give bool(false) to `var_dump`, it will in fact print bool(false).

also, when debugging `curl` code specifically, enable `CURLOPT_VERBOSE`, it prints lots of useful debugging info. and when `curl_exec` returns **false**, you should use `curl_error()` to extract the error message.

in short, replace `$result = curl_exec($c);` with:

```
curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,true);
$result = curl_exec($c);
if(false===$result){
throw new \RuntimeException('curl_exec failed! errno: '.curl_errno($c).'. error: '.curl_error($c));
}
var_dump($result);
```

additionally, if there's a problem setting any of your curl options, curl_setopt returns bool(false) , which you also completely ignore here, don't do that! use something like:

```
function ecurl_setopt ( /*resource*/$ch , int $option , /*mixed*/ $value ):bool{
    $ret=curl_setopt($ch,$option,$value);
    if($ret!==true){
        //option should be obvious by stack trace
        throw new RuntimeException ( 'curl_setopt() failed. curl_errno: ' .  curl_errno ($ch).'. curl_error: '.curl_error($ch) );
    }
    return true;
}
```

now, instead of silently ignoring setopt errors, an exception will be thrown if there's a problem applying your settings. anyway, apply `CURLOPT_VERBOSE`, don't ignore `setopt` return value, and use `var_dump` instead of `print_r`, and if it still doesn't work, print the VERBOSE log, and whatever was printed by `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` and `var_dump` and `curl_error`, THEN i will retract my close vote.